# Como fazer o redirecionamento de endereços na rede interna pelo modem?

Tags: apache, servidor, redirecionamento, nginx

Gostaria de saber como redirecionar endereços locais dentro da rede interna através do modem, por exemplo: se alguém dentro da rede acessar o endereço www.exemplo.com.br deverá ser redirecionada para uma página especifica em uma máquina da rede.
Se possível gostaria de uma forma que o modem identificasse o endereço registrado e apontasse para a máquina que eu quero.

Obs: É possível fazer esses redirecionamentos através do apache ou pelo nginx porém é necessário fazer o redirecionamento em cada máquina.

Comment: Caio, isso deve ser feito no seu servidor de DNS não no NGINX.

Comment: Alguma ideia de como isso seria feito?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Impossível responder a sua pergunta porque existem milhares de modelos de modens, cada um com mais recursos ou menos recursos, e visto que você não especificou marca nem modelo.

Porém minha recomendação é você utilizar um computador como servidor de internet, ele fará a função de servidor DHCP e DNS - obviamente para isso ele terá que ter 2 placas de rede, pois ele será um intermediário entre a internet e os computadores da rede local - Além disso também é mais efetivo você implementar um squid proxy (apenas para redirecionamento mesmo) ou fazer regras no firewall iptables garantindo o redirecionamento, pois em muitos casos o cliente pode alterar o dns na maquina (exemplo o da google) perdendo então o redirecionamento no caso de implementação por DNS local.

Boa sorte!

Comment: Ok. Muito obrigado.